# Can't add two numbers while using If()

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been trying to add 1 to the the false result of the `If`, like the following image

[image: Click here]

I want the value of cell D4 to be as the following

If E4 = "R" then the value of D4 should be 0 else should be increase by 1

This the full range that i want to start counting form the last R in that range

[image: 11111]

The first row is all T&I so leve it untouch
The secund row the R count sholud start from the last R in that row and the ruslet should be  9 cell contine S/B

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to count the entries in `E4:G4` that are not `R`?  If so, maybe `D4: =COUNTIF(E4:G4,"<>R")`. Otherwise, please clarify what you are looking for in D4 given different distributions of `R` in `E4:G4`

Comment: What is the original value in D4 ?

Comment: Iam trying to count how many S/B cells after the last R ,

Comment: In your example, there are zero `S/B` cells after the last `R`. They are all before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this :

```
=COUNTIF(E4:I4,"R")
```

Please share if it works/not.

Comment: I have tryied that but i want it to start counting form the last cell that contine R

Comment: u may change the range `E4:G4` to cover the range that u want.. (I put that range coz that is the formula in ur screenshot) | I had updated the formula to cover until column I, u may change the range depending on ur need. | u can refer to [excel help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) & [other guide](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function) to see/learn on how it works in detail..

Comment: any luck so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(E4:G4="R"))
```

[image]